# Calculation in Play 2.0 Framework template engine

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Does play 2.0 template engine support the simple calculation in the html page.

Let us say, I create a sum.scala.html page:

```
@(a:String, b: String)

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1> answer is getSum(@a,@b) </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way that we could "getSum of a and b" via some function? or Does any play 2.0 expert know any good idea about calculation in play 2.0 template engine? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried `@(a.toInt + b.toInt)`?

Comment: +1 works for me, anyway this supports very basic operations as I can see.

Comment: Play 2.0 allow to put single arbitrary scala expression inside `@( )` and multiple expressions inside `@{ }`, so you can use full power of scala language and library in templates. But of course controller is better place for complex computations.

Answer (score 3):

You can just pass the value to template, can't you ?

```
@(a:String, b: String, c: String)

<h1> answer for @a + @b is @c </h1>
```

You can also call function from `Yourcontroller` in the template:

```
@Yourcontroller.getSum(a,b);
```

In `/app/controllers/Yourcontroller.java` ad the function (simplest sample):

```
public static Integer getSum(String a, String b){
    Integer c = Integer.valueOf(a) + Integer.valueOf(b);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, biesior. We can do it in your way, but what if there are not just 2 variables. For example, we may want to calculate sum(a+b), sum(d+e) and so on. In addition, if use this html as data report page. What about to calculation of percentage ( a / (a + b) )

Comment: @Chan: added next tip in last edition, should satisfy you. Anyway be careful with types, most probably you'll need to convert between String and numeric types to keep it working.

Comment: Thanks, biesior. `@Yourcontroller.getSum(a,b);` is great. Now I can do more calculation on my data report page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice, anyway I must to add, that incrop's solution works too. Please mark question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to the result multiple times, you can use `defining`:

```
@defining(a.toInt + b.toInt) { sum =>
  <h1>The sum is @sum</h1>
  The sum of @a + @b is @sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reuse of your code in scala html template. You can make a template function in template for this.

```
@sum(a:Long,b:Long) = {
@(a + b)
}
```

And call this in your template as normal functions. Like
    @sum(2,3)