# playframework: How to perform arithmetic operations in scala view

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculation in Play 2.0 Framework template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024880/calculation-in-play-2-0-framework-template-engine)

If I have some view say page.scala.html and I passed a hash map to this view. Now I want to extract and perform some arithmetic operations on this page like this:

```
    @pageMap.get("newPt") - @pageMap.get("oldPt") = 
(((@pageMap.get("oldPt")) - (@pageMap.get("newPt")))
```

but instead of printing the diff on right side I got the values of `"oldPt"` and `"newPt"` something like this:

50 - 40 = (((50)) - ((40)))

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024880/calculation-in-play-2-0-framework-template-engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write blocks of scala codes using the @( ... ) or @{ ... } syntax.

```
@pageMap.get("newPt") - @pageMap.get("oldPt") = @{pageMap.get("oldPt") - pageMap.get("newPt")}
```